# calculate distance and fuel consumption on each fuel filling

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
+--------+------+-------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------+----------+------------------+
| Number |  Id  | Speed |     DateTime     |     x      |     y      | value |  distance   |    ds    |     remarks      |
+--------+------+-------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------+----------+------------------+
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/24/20 12:05 AM | 73.1095066 | 33.54376   | 405.6 | 0.033162654 | NULL     |                  |
| MB125  | 6290 |    26 | 9/24/20 5:38 PM  | 73.1548833 | 33.5737866 | 398.8 | 0.45217702  | 3.2      | Filling(3.2)     |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/26/20 3:42 PM  | 71.2384983 | 31.502485  | 189.4 | 0           | 0.9      | adjustment (0.9) |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/26/20 4:13 PM  | 71.2351549 | 31.4826683 | 389   | 0.144494657 | 202.5    | Filling(202.5)   |
| MB125  | 6290 |     5 | 9/26/20 4:15 PM  | 71.2348366 | 31.4813966 | 392.6 | 0.182010336 | 3.6      | Filling(3.6)     |
| MB125  | 6290 |     5 | 9/26/20 4:17 PM  | 71.2351333 | 31.4797783 | 392.3 | 0.139413206 | -0.3     |                  |
| MB125  | 6290 |    16 | 9/27/20 11:44 AM | 71.637325  | 29.3697783 | 260.2 | 0.453226377 | 0        |                  |
| MB125  | 6290 |    19 | 9/27/20 11:46 AM | 71.641335  | 29.3718816 | 260.7 | 0.343467266 | 0.5      | adjustment (0.5) |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/27/20 11:48 AM | 71.6439233 | 29.373995  | 260.1 | 0.07865584  | -0.6     |                  |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/27/20 1:02 PM  | 71.6434633 | 29.3734116 | 400.6 | 0.00648517  | 140.5    | Filling(140.5)   |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/29/20 6:15 PM  | 67.2537633 | 24.8577533 | 150.5 | 0.036963575 | 0.4      | adjustment (0.4) |
| MB125  | 6290 |     8 | 9/29/20 6:17 PM  | 67.253455  | 24.8575733 | 150   | 0.163134678 | -0.5     |                  |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/29/20 6:19 PM  | 67.25335   | 24.8561083 | 151.4 | 0.000750227 | 1.4      | adjustment (1.4) |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/29/20 6:21 PM  | 67.253355  | 24.8561033 | 151.9 | 0.065821168 | 0.5      | adjustment (0.5) |
| MB125  | 6290 |     5 | 9/29/20 6:23 PM  | 67.253165  | 24.85667   | 151.2 | 0.004457236 | -0.7     |                  |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/29/20 6:25 PM  | 67.2531683 | 24.85663   | 169.6 | 0           | 18.4     | Filling(18.4)    |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/29/20 6:29 PM  | 67.2531683 | 24.85663   | 315.7 | 0.074685692 | 146.1    | Filling(146.1)   |
| MB125  | 6290 |     9 | 9/29/20 6:31 PM  | 67.2525283 | 24.8562916 | 366.2 | 0.099031196 | 50.5     | Filling(50.5)    |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/29/20 6:33 PM  | 67.2515583 | 24.8561516 | 382.4 | 0           | 16.2     | Filling(16.2)    |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/29/20 6:35 PM  | 67.2515583 | 24.8561516 | 386.2 | 0.017310501 | 3.8      | Filling(3.8)     |
| MB125  | 6290 |     0 | 9/30/20 11:59 PM | 67.0170466 | 24.83925   | 381.8 | NULL        | -1.2     |                  |
+--------+------+-------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------+----------+------------------+
```

**Required output**

```
+--------+------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
| Number |  Id  |    from date     |      todate      |   from x   |   from y   |    To x    |   To Y    | from Value | to Value | distance | Filling |
+--------+------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
| MB125  | 6290 | 9/24/20 12:05 AM | 9/26/20 3:42 PM  | 73.1095066 | 33.54376   | 71.2384983 | 31.502485 | 405.6      | 189.4    | 0.8118   | 206.1   |
| MB126  | 6291 | 9/26/20 4:15 PM  | 9/27/20 11:48 AM | 71.2348366 | 31.4813966 | 71.6439233 | 29.373995 | 392.6      | 260.1    | 1.014    | 140.5   |
+--------+------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

I want to calulate distance and fuel consumption of vehicle on each filling. I am using below query to extract required result and result is seperated by at the time of fuel filling . I am using sql server 2012 to extract required result.

```
SELECT
    Number,
    ObjectId,
    VectorSpeed,
    GpsTime,
    x,
    y,
    [value],
    distance,
    ds,
    CASE 
        WHEN ( CAST( ds AS float(5) ) > CAST( 0 AS float(5) ) ) AND ( CAST( ds AS float(5) ) <= CAST( 3 AS float(5) ) ) THEN 'adjustment (' + ds + ')'
        ELSE [status]
    END AS remarks
FROM (

    SELECT
      *,
      CASE
        WHEN ( [value] - ( LAG( [value] ) OVER ( ORDER BY t.GpsTime ) ) ) > 0 then 'Filling(' + CAST( [value] - ( LAG( [value] ) OVER ( ORDER BY t.GpsTime ) ) AS varchar(50) ) + ')'
        ELSE ''
      END AS 'status',
      CAST( [value] - ( LAG( [value] ) OVER ( ORDER BY t.GpsTime ) ) AS varchar(50) ) AS ds,
      LAG( [value] ) OVER ( ORDER BY t.GpsTime ) AS PreviousValue,
      LEAD( [value] ) OVER ( ORDER BY t.GpsTime ) AS NextValue,
      tavl2.tavl.fn_GpsUtil_Distance(
        x,
        y,
        LEAD( x ) OVER ( PARTITION BY objectid ORDER BY GpsTime ),
        LEAD( y ) OVER ( PARTITION BY objectid ORDER BY GpsTime )
      ) AS distance
    FROM (
        
        SELECT
          LEAD( m.VectorSpeed ) OVER ( PARTITION BY o.ObjectId, o.Number ORDER BY m.GpsTime ) AS NextSpeed,
          LAG( m.VectorSpeed ) OVER ( PARTITION BY o.ObjectId, o.Number ORDER BY m.GpsTime ) AS PrevSpeed,
          o.Number,
          m.ObjectId,
          VectorSpeed,
          GpsTime,
          x,
          y,
          [value]
        FROM tavl2.tavl.Object o
          JOIN tavl2.tavl.Message m ON o.ObjectId = m.ObjectId
          JOIN tavl2.tavl.MessageData md ON m.MessageId = md.MessageId
          JOIN tavl2.tavl.DataSource ds ON md.DataSourceId = ds.DataSourceId
        WHERE
          m.ObjectId = 6290
          AND CONVERT( date, GpsTime ) >= CONVERT( date, '2020/9/24' )
          AND CONVERT( date, GpsTime ) <= CONVERT( date, '2020/9/30' )
          AND [name] LIKE '%Fuel Level%'
          AND [value] > 1
      
    ) AS t
    WHERE
      t.VectorSpeed <> COALESCE( t.NextSpeed, -1 )
      OR t.VectorSpeed <> COALESCE( t.PrevSpeed, -1 )

) AS main;
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for determining what a trip is.  I would expect 4 trips.

Comment: question update, calculation on each filling with new row

Comment: What is ID, Number, DS and other stuff? It makes no sence to paste all the data you have and ask to write some query on it. Reverse-engeneering of the code is also waste of time. Shrink columns to only used in algorithm and describe the logic which you shoud translate to code

Comment: id and number belong to vehicle and ds is the difference of previous and current value of fuel.